Conditional resource creation in terraform
I'm new to Terraform, having recently transitioned from CloudFormation. The resources for my service were initially created using CloudFormation but are now managed by Terraform.
I've encountered a challenge:
If a new region is introduced in the future, my Terraform code should be able to create and manage all required resources without relying on the old CloudFormation code.
I need to create some resources conditionally using Terraform:

If it is a new region(that means there is no secret created yet), then create these additional resources.

If it is an existing region(the secret for this region is present), no need to create these resources.


The count meta-argument isn't working for this scenario. Here's the list of resources I need to manage conditionally:
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "new_db_password" {
  count = local.secret_exists ? 0 : 1

  name = "${var.SecretPrefix}-my-service/RDS/password"
  description    = "password for new my service RDS"
  tags           = {
    "Application"   = "${var.SecretPrefix}-my-service"
    "resourceowner" = "${var.owner}"
  }
  tags_all       = {
    "Application"   = "${var.SecretPrefix}-my-service"
    "resourceowner" = "${var.owner}"
  }
}

resource "random_password" "new_rds_password" {
  count = local.secret_exists ? 0 : 1

  length = 12
  special = false
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "my_rds_pwd_secret_version" {
  count = local.secret_exists ? 0 : 1

  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.new_db_password.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    password = random_password.new_rds_password.result
  })
}

Here's how I am setting the varible "secret_exists":
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "existing_db_password" {
  name = "${var.SecretPrefix}-my-service/RDS/password"
}

locals {
  secret_exists = try(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.existing_db_password.arn != "", false)
}

Based on "secret_exists" variable, I need to take the decision to create/not create a resource.
Any advice or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
I tried using count meta argument, but it doesn't work
  count = local.secret_exists ? 0 : 1

This doesn't work. I am getting following error:
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on rds.tf line 87, in resource "random_password" "new_rds_password":
  87:   count   = aws_secretsmanager_secret.new_db_password.count

Because aws_secretsmanager_secret.new_db_password has "count" set, its
attributes must be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_secretsmanager_secret.new_db_password[count.index]

Error: Invalid resource count attribute


What exactly do you mean by The count meta-argument isn't working for this scenario? And how is local.secret_exists being set?

Well, terraform doesn't work the same way CloudFormation does, so you would probably have to define provider aliases for each of the regions, or alternatively have a tfvars file where you set the region for the single provider configuration. Another thing worth mentioning is the data source aws_regions, which, if configured, can return the list of all regions. Then, you could write a module and provide the list as input. In any case, you would need to find a way to tell terraform in which particular region you want to create a secret.

@RuiJarimba, I have set up the variable like this:
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "existing_db_password" {
name = "${var.SecretPrefix}-my-service/RDS/password"
}
locals {
secret_exists = try(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.existing_db_password.arn != "", false)
}
I wanted to use "count" to create the resource conditionally, like if the value of "secret_exists" is true, that means the secret is already created, so no need to create it

@abyk007 it's very hard to read code in the comments. Please edit your question and add the relevant part of the code there.

@MarkoE, yes I have separate tfvars files for all regions, its just that for this new region, I have to create some resources, which will not be created for existing regions, and since the code is present in the same main.tf which creates resources in all regions, i want these 3 resources created only for new region, and not for the old existing ones.

@RuiJarimba please check the latest edits

@abyk007 so the secret needs to be created in that new region and other things don't?

Double-check that local.secret_exists really has the expected value. Try for example to add an output variable named secret_exists that shows the value of the local variable.

@MarkoE the secret needs to be created in the new region only, and not in other regions. So, the secret is the only resources that should be made conditional, other resources are present but they do not need to be conditional

Ok, and do you have a variable for the region defined?

@RuiJarimba Please check the latest edit, I have added the error I am getting.

@MarkoE yes, I have the region defined

Ok, so, a couple of things: you didn't add the part of the code which reports the error. And second, it would probably make things easier if you were to use the region variable for count, e.g, count = var.region == "new region" ? 1 : 0.

@MarkoE , Please check my latest edit, I have added the error. My understanding is if the variable value is false, the count will be set to 1 and it will create the resource

I see the error, I don't see the part of the code which produces it. From what I can see in the error, that's simply not how the way count works.

@MarkoE, is there any other way to acheive this then?

I would try with count = var.region == "new region" ? 1 : 0, where the "new region" is the ID of the region you want to deploy the secret into.

Thank you for your help guys, I was able to fix this using for_each

To conditionally create resources in Terraform based on whether the secret already exists, you can use the count meta-argument along with conditional expressions and data sources. The key is to structure your Terraform code in a way that allows for the conditional creation of resources without causing errors.

Check for the existence of the secret using a data source.
Set a local variable based on the existence of the secret.
Use the count meta-argument with conditional expressions.

